# PostgreSQL - How to insert data to array of composite type which has only 1 attribute?

Tags: postgresql

Disclaimer: These below examples make no sense.

This code works:

```
CREATE TYPE item AS (
    name    text,
    price   int
);

CREATE TYPE items_pack AS (
    items   item[],
    count   int
);

CREATE TABLE player (
    items_packs     items_pack[],
    name            text
);

INSERT INTO player VALUES (
    ARRAY[
        (ARRAY[
            ('sword', 100)::item, 
            ('hammer', 200)::item
        ], 2)::items_pack, 
        (ARRAY[
            ('knife', 300)::item, 
            ('gun', 400)::item
        ], 2)::items_pack
    ],
    'anyname'
);
```

But this doesn't work (the count attribute was removed from items_pack type):

```
CREATE TYPE item AS (
    name    text,
    price   int
);

CREATE TYPE items_pack AS (
    items   item[]
    -- count is removed
);

CREATE TABLE player (
    items_packs     items_pack[],
    name            text
);

INSERT INTO player VALUES (
    ARRAY[
        (ARRAY[
            ('sword', 100)::item, 
            ('hammer', 200)::item
        ])::items_pack, 
        (ARRAY[
            ('knife', 300)::item, 
            ('gun', 400)::item
        ])::items_pack
    ],
    'anyname'
);
```

ERROR:  cannot cast type item[] to items_pack

It seems like the syntax is inconsistent? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Try `... row(array[...])::items_pack ...`

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: You should to explicitly provide the `row` key word if there is only one item in it: [Row Constructors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). Good luck.